# Cannot run Google Chrome normally

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, google-chrome

I've just installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 16.04 on my Virtual Box virtual machine. I've also installed Chrome, but when I try to run it I see what it is on the picture below. I installed all available updates for Ubuntu and downloaded the latest version for chrome. On the image the black rectagle is Chrome window

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Did you install Guest Additions?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes i did, even before Ubuntu system updates

Comment: You will probably need to disable some graphical features in chrome://flags. What is the VB version?

Comment: @Pilot6 the problem is that Chrome menu is not accessible for me. There is literally nothing i can click in this buggy black window. I cannot click anything, I cannot type anything in, nothing. That's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ok, the problem was that for my virtual machine 3D acceleration was enabled. Switching it off solves this problem though it makes the whole interface not working smooth enough, which is another story.

Finalyzing and summing up all comments and updates, here is the workaround for this:

1. switch off 3d accelartion for VM in VM settings
2. Start the system, run Chrome, switch off hardware acceleration in Chrome settings(just search for acceleration in search string)
3. Switch off VM, enable 3d acceleration back and start the machine again. Chrome should be working normally now.

Comment: You can disable acceleration in Chrome, then enable it back in VB.

Comment: @Pilot6 wow that was awesome! I will do it